# How to access a view from layout specified in headerLayout of NavigationView using Kotlin in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I want to access a TextView which is included inside headerLayout of NavigationView. Is it possible to access the view using Kotlin android extension? I did using this method, but the TextView (here txtName) is always null.

Here is my **activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_splash"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_splash_drawer" />
```

**nav_header_splash.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:text="@string/name"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

in **MainActivity.kt**  I have imported

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.nav_header_splash.*
```

in `onCreate()` of Activity class I set text like

```
txtName.text = "Sample Code"
```

**build.gradle** of app folder

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

**build.gradle** of my project

```
 classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
```

Is there any mistake in my code? Please help. I'm new in Kotlin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not  `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.nav_header_splash.*`  it will be available from the main file itself as

instead `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.nav_header_splash.view.*`

and get view by using

```
val header = mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0)
header.txtName.text = "Sample Code"
```